# Unable to pass the variable's value from parent component to child component in angular

Tags: angular

I am not able to view the value of parent component in child's component

I have added eventDidMount in fullcalendar options as below in parents component. ts file.

```
eventDidMount: (info) =>  {
    
    info.el.addEventListener('click',  function() {
      clickCnt++;
      if(clickCnt === 1) {
        
        self.parentMessage = idCal(info.el, eventsarr)
        console.log('Please add tooltip/mattooltip')
      }
      else if (clickCnt === 2) {
        self.parentMessage = idCal(info.el, eventsarr)
        window.open('scheduler/editevents',"_self");
      }
    })
    
  },
```

In the parent html,

```
<app-editevents [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-editevents>
```

Child component .ts :

```
export class EditeventsComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() childMessage: number;
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

and child component html

```
<p>Say {{childMessage}}</p>
```

This shows the desired value in the parent component page (Say 8), but not in the childs page (Say ).can someone help me where I am doing wrong?

Comment: Where are you setting `this.parentMessage`?

Comment: Btw there is an event for double click too https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/dblclick_event

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm Thanks for the tip, I want to display a tooltip when I did single click and navigate to child's page for double click

Comment: @Alex In parents HTML I am setting

Comment: No where in your TypeScript are you setting the value of `this.parentMessage`. You might be passing `parentMessage` to your child in your HTML but nowhere in your example do you assign `parentMessage` a value.

Comment: @Alex , I have defined a function idCal which returns and assigns the value to the this.parentMessage, and when I used `<app-editevents [childMessage]="parentMessage"></app-editevents>` It is visible in the parent component and the child component only returns Say

Comment: Can you try and initialize parentMessage with a value? Like: public parentMessage: string = "test"; And see if that gets rendered in the child component? Also iam a little uncertain you should use self.variable in Angular, havent seen it before.

Comment: @Tommi I just tried your suggestion and I got back with **Say** in child's component

Comment: Can you post a working example (e.g. StackBlitz) then?

Comment: So the string "Say" is rendered in the child component? Also is parentMessage and childMessage supposed to be string values or number? Because in childMessage you've given it the type number. I second @Alex that a stackblitz or some sort of example would be needed.

Comment: The issue is almost definitely that you're using `self` like it's the keyword `this` but it's hard to tell with the code you're given. Self is not interchangeable with this, it's a property of the browser `window` object and probably isn't available to Angular when it's trying to work out your component bindings. Just create `this.parentMessage` and set it, then it will work.

Comment: @Alex, I tried Stack Blitz  for showing the example. But I culd not because I have to change the Data which is companies related and I need to change it in many places. However, The say is rendered in component and the parentMessage and childMessage contains number. I tried using this, but in the above code which I have mentioned this refers to the HTML element but not to the actual this. So at the beginning of the calendar options I have defined `let self = this'.